# arrays with same memory location, which will show as output

Tags: java

please have a look on the below array prog:

```
    public class array {

    public static <t> void main(String[] args) {

    String  str[]= new String[5];
    str[0]= "aaa";
    str[1]= "bbb";
    str[3]= "ccc";
    str[3]= "ddd";
    str[4]= "eee";

    for (int x=0; x<str.length; x++)

      System.out.println(str[x]);

     }
 }

   output: 
    aaa
    bbb
    null
    ddd
    eee
```

question is.. why did it show the output 'null' for 3rd data and not "ccc". and why the 4th data is shown.

Comment: watch the indices used...

Answer (score 2):

You want to change

```
str[3]= "ccc";
```

to

```
str[2]= "ccc";
```

First you stored "ccc" in `str[3]`. Then you stored "ddd" in the same index. Therefore, the array no longer has a reference to "ccc". You never assigned anything to `str[2]`, which is why it stayed `null`.

Comment: no i want to know y did it print only ddd and not ccc... in that location the data ccc was stored first then later ddd, if i am not wrong.

Comment: @abhijitpaulchowdhury edited answer. You can't store reference to two Strings in the same index of a String array.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing index 2 that's why there is no value at index 2.
If you are createing string array it's defoult value if `null` That's why index 2 printing `null` value.

```
String  str[]= new String[5];
        str[0]= "aaa";
        str[1]= "bbb";
        str[2]= "ccc";  // change 3 index to 2
        str[3]= "ddd";
        str[4]= "eee";
```

Comment: ok.. i got it.. i wanted to knw if we keep

str[0]= "aaa"; 
str[1]= "bbb";
str[3]= "ccc";  ---- if both location is [3] so which one will print.. and  why.?
 str[3]= "ddd";----
 str[4]= "eee";

Comment: you are overriding index 3, right? last assign value will print in this case.